# file_get_contents('YOUTUBE API') returns cached/non-updated/old information

Tags: youtube-api

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/EXAMPLE/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc

When visiting this url direct from a browser, it will return the correct data 100% of the time. If a video has been added, it's there, if a video has been deleted, it's gone.

When getting this data through file_get_contents('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/EXAMPLE/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc');

The data seems to be cached or not updated/current data...

If you continue refreshing the page, it will show/hide new videos, as well as show/hide deleted videos for about 5-10 minutes, then it will be accurate.

The same thing happens when I get data using $.getJSON(), or $.ajax()...

Shouldn't the data be the same as when visiting the url in the browser?

I'm simply trying to get the most recent video uploaded by a user "EXAMPLE".

```
public function ajaxUpdateVideoFeed()
{
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        $json = file_get_contents('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/EXAMPLE/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc');
        $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        $videoId = $data['data']['items'][0]['id'];
        echo json_encode($videoId);die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending a random number to the end of you url call. `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/EXAMPLE/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&r=RAND`  where `RAND` would be some arbitrary randomly generated number each time the url is called. Not sure if this will work for you, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: Chase, I tried adding a rand(), to the end of the url call, it did not fix the problem. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue. I'm trying to retrieve current state of a specific video via $.ajax() call, and the response data appears to stay cached. If I try the url from a browser the data is updated.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/YouTubeID?v=2&alt=json'
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
        var ytState = response.entry.app$control.yt$state.name;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log( "The following error occured: "+ textStatus + errorThrown );
    },
    complete: function(){   
    }
});
```

I have tried json, jsonp, cached=false, appending a time stamp, appending my developer key to url, and no success.

****EDIT**

By using POST vs GET in my ajax request it seems to eliminate my similar caching issue.

**EDIT EDIT**

Nevermind, I suck. Using POST is producing a 400 error.

Comment: So weird. I tried something along the lines of your approach using PHP and file_get_contents() and I thought I had working, but the caching issue still pops up intermittently.